# select parent child account from row_number using CASE WHEN (SQL)

Tags: sql

**I would like to use CASE WHEN to select ORDER_NUMBER from that same group of id0, Which the pairing conditions are as follows:**

- A pair with B (A is the main type order. B is the minor type  order) and B pairs with C
- X pair with Y (X is the main type order. Y is the minor type order) and Y pairs with Z

  ```
  id0   id1     ORDER_NUMBER       ORDER_NUMBER_2    Type    RN
  ---+--------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+----
  47   48      2000036                 0              A       1
  47   49      300026660000            0              B       2
  47   49      300026660001        300026660000       C       3
  250  251     2000341                 0              X       1
  250  252     300000193000            0              Y       2
  250  252     300000193001        300000193000       Z       3
  ```

**Expected result:**

```
   Type_main| Type_minor| ORDER_NUMBER_main  | ORDER_NUMBER_minor
------------+----------+---------------------+----------------------
    A      |    B      | 2000036             |  300026660000
    B      |    C      | 300026660000        |  300026660001
    X      |    Y      | 2000341             |  300000193000
    Y      |    Z      | 300000193000        |  300000193001
```

Comment: What have you tried, do you have a query we can help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `join` to the table itself, you can easily achieve the desired result

```
SELECT T.Type_main,T.Type_minor,T.ORDER_NUMBER_main,T.ORDER_NUMBER_minor
FROM
     (SELECT 
        t1.Type AS Type_main,
        t2.Type AS Type_minor,
        t1.ORDER_NUMBER AS ORDER_NUMBER_main,
        t2.ORDER_NUMBER AS ORDER_NUMBER_minor,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.Type ORDER BY t1.id0) seq
     FROM myTable t1
     JOIN
     myTable t2 ON t1.id0 = t2.id0 and t1.RN < t2.RN) T
WHERE T.seq = 1
```

*demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f2010ede95e8b536b1f3cbea7b89263f)*